# Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException for MahApps DLL

Tags: c#, exception, reflection, .net-assembly, mahapps.metro

Today I've had a curious issue. After making a realse (I did not change any references), i get an `Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException` which says, that it coul don't load a type in `MahApps.Metro`.

The curious thing is, that I have no assembly which references `MahApps`.

What else could cause this issue? I've debug and searched a lot, but could not find anything.

**EDIT**

Sometimes the exception occurse only the first time I do some action. If i open a windows the second time, everything works.

Thank you all!

Comment: Are you using any other UI libraries that might be giving you an indirect requirement for MahApps?

Comment: Just using Telerik and Xceed, but it's worked for over 2 years now, and with the current release i changed nothing at htis point.

Comment: You didn't update your telerik/Xceed versions?

Comment: @DanielCasserly no, did not changed anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tool like [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) find where the dependency is coming from.  Just inspect each assembly in your bin folder until you find the one that references MahApps.

[image]

Comment: Ok, problem solved. In some code i loaded assemblies and tried to load the references assemblies also programatically. That caused the issue. Finding this out, ILSpy helped a lot. Thanks :)